# Google Drive API v3 & Google Picker: Change the download permission of file

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-picker

I've used Google Picker API to retrieve My Drive videos URLs and publish them in my app. So I want to change their [sharing permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) (as public) and disabled the download button with the [copyRequiresWriterPermission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) option.

This is my code for change the permissions in the Picker callback function;

```
function pickerCallback(data, e) {
    if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var docs = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS];
        var type = "anyone";
        var role = "reader";
        var urls = new Array();
        
        for (var d = 0; d < docs.length; d++) {
            var request1 = gapi.client.request({
              'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + docs[d].id + '/permissions',
              'method': 'POST',
              'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
              },
              'body':{
                'role': role,
                'type': type
              }
            });
            request1.execute(function(resp) {
              console.log(resp);
            });

            urls.push(docs[d].url);
        }

        elements.push({name: 'url', value: urls});

        // continue with an ajax funtion ...
    
    }
};
```

That works fine, so I decided add a new request for change the donwload restriction:

```
var request2 = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + docs[d].id,
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
    },
    'body':{
        'copyRequiresWriterPermission': true
    }
});
request2.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
});
```

But only I obtained a 404 status. Also, I've tried with:

```
'/upload/drive/v3/files/' + docs[d].id
```

But the same problem.

[image]

I've tried the request with the File Id in the Drive API Demo and works. What is the error in the request2 code?

Scopes used:

```
var scope = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
];
```

**Updated code**:

```
    var request2 = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + docs[d].id ,
        'method': 'PATCH',
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
        },
        'body':{copyRequiresWriterPermission: true}
                    
    });
   request2.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
   });
```

This code execute without problems, but nothing happens because I need to uncheck this parameter:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand where you say you need to uncheck that option. Can you explain where?

Comment: My app attach videos from the Google Picker API, so I need to prevent users download them (directly). I need to change this option in the sharing config of my video in My Drive, so this will disable the download button when users preview the video.

Comment: And you are saying the request to update the file with request2 is not updating the file?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure is this is the correct way (if is it possible)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **update** a File in drive, the request method should be `PATCH` not `POST`.

### Example:

```js
var request2 = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + docs[d].id,
    'method': 'PATCH',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
    },
    'body': {
        copyRequiresWriterPermission: true
    }

});
request2.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
});
```

#### References:

- [Drive API Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

Comment: Thank you, now show an execution, but don't update the download parameter. I'v update my post

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "don't update the download parameter". I think you are using the "copyRequiresWriterPermission" wrong, you may want to set it to false, if you want users to be able to download it without permission.