# Google Drive api Error gapi.client.request

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

Hello guys I am using Google Picker API but when i comes to this code

```
var request1 =  gapi.client.request({
                        'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + fileID + '/permissions',
                        'method': 'POST',
                        'headers': {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
                        },
                        'body': {
                            'role': role,
                            'type': type
                        }
                    });
                    request1.execute(function (resp) {
                        console.log(resp);
                    });
```

I keep on getting error on gapi.client.request, you see in the image below.
I don't what Im doing wrong here I also search alot in the google. And this code is also same with the code that I found in google and I need this to run in my website but I keep getting this error.

Any idea will do thank you.
[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the library takes a bit of time to complete before it is fully loaded. So when you try to use `gapi.client.request`, `gapi.client` is still undefined.

Make sure the library is loaded before proceeding.

#### Sample:

```
<body>
  Tester2
  <script>
    googleApiClientReady = function () {
      var request1 =  gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + fileID + '/permissions',
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',           
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
        },
        'body': {
          'role': role,
          'type': type
        }
      });
      request1.execute(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
</body>
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Error now proceeds to undefined `fileID` instead of undefined `gapi.client`, inferring that the latter is now defined.

#### Note:

- If you want to update a file in drive, method should be `PATCH` not `POST`. (reference: [PATCH vs POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63030827/14606045))